Python package installed, but getting import error in Jupyter notebook
Fresh install of Python 3.12.5 on Mac OS.
Getting import error in Jupyter notebook:

But works fine in terminal:

I am not using any virtual environment either.
Here's where terminal shows python and pip are installed:

And here's where Jupyter notebook says python and pip are installed:

So, its pointing to the same path (I checked in case Jupyter might be using a different pip internally, but that seems to not be the case).
So what's wrong? And how do I fix it?

What seemed to work is this:
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install tiktoken

But previously I've always used !pip install <package> in Jupyter notebooks, or I do pip install <package> in terminal and am able to import the package inside Jupyter notebook. It's only after freshly installing Python (to upgrade the Python version) that I'm noticing this behaviour. Does anybody know how I can get back to installing packages the simpler way like I used to before? I don't want to have to run !{sys.executable} -m pip install <package> every time I want to install a new package; not to mention that I would also like to be able to install packages from terminal and then import them in Jupyter notebook.

"previously I've always used !pip install  in Jupyter notebooks, " But you shouldn't be! You just got lucky you didn't have an issue until now. What you have been doing was outdated since 2019. Because of problems like you are having they added the magic version, %pip install to ensure the installation done inside a running Jupyter Notebook installs to the environment the kernel backing the notebook is using. The exclamation point doesn't do that and so many others had the problem you are facing right now. And so the magic version was added to fix this. See more about ...

 See more about the modern %pip install command here. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues. The magic version is easier to remember than the complex !{sys.executable} -m pip install tiktoken. And the magic version works more universally know because it works in JupyterLite, too.

Here’s a guide to updating python version in macOS.
You need to update the python path in your macOS so that the alias python is mapped to the correct path.
